# How to run React native Application in real android device

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I want to connect my device with my React native project.
I have already gone through the documentation part, I set up my device by enabling developers mode and USB debugging I have connected my device with USB.
Checked the ADB device I think it is also there and connected.
But when I run the command npx react-native run-android
I am getting this error

> `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\native\test\android\local.properties'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081`

**What should I need to do now ? **

Comment: The error is pretty clear,react native couldn't find the sdk of android you need to install it or correct path

Comment: This might help https://youtu.be/KRLLjlpy0r4

Comment: ohk thanks I setup the local.properties files inside Android folder but its still failing the new error is Failed to install the app. Please accept all necessary Android SDK licenses using Android SDK Manager: "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses"

Comment: Go to Configure>SDK Manager in your Android Studio.

Select SDK Tools tab and install Google Play Licensing Library